# how to launch ListActivity using an intent?

Tags: android, listactivity

```
public class ListPage extends ListActivity
{

ListView months;
ArrayAdapter my;
String[] monthlist = {"jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sept", "oct", "nov", "dec"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_page);

    months = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    my = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,monthlist);

    months.setAdapter(my);
}
```

}

I am tryin to launch this ListActivity from another activity, but gettin an error "04-30 08:30:45.234:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.listinflator_demo/com.example.listinflator_demo.
ListPage}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView 
whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"
```

if I change `extends ListActivity` to `extends Activity`, the code works just fine. How do I make it work using `extends ListActivity` ??

Comment: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ListActivity** has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

so add  `android:id="@android:id/list"` in listview in your list_page.xml

like:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) for more detail. here is [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listactivity_layout)

---

**Edited:**

if you are use ListActivity then your code will be:

```
public class ListPage extends ListActivity
{


ArrayAdapter my;
String[] monthlist = {"jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sept", "oct", "nov", "dec"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_page);



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, monthlist );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: "months = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);"

now this line shows an error which says "list cannot be resolved or is not a field"

wat do I do now ?

Answer (score 1):

Your error clearly indicates:

> E/AndroidRuntime(2010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listinflator_demo/com.example.listinflator_demo.ListPage}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Make sure that in the XML Layout file: `list_page` that you are setting as the `contentView` for you `Activity` you defined the `ListView` object with id: `list`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use ArrayAdapter of type string since you have used string-array to store the months

```
ArrayAdapter<string> my = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,monthlist);
```

PS:: *remove the ArrayAdapter declaration in the beginning while you make the following above changes*